# Running a GAMM suddenly results in the "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a random smooth model that I successfully ran half a year and when I ran it again, R gave me the error mentioned above. Has anybody experienced this? As I said: Nothing changed so I guess it could have something to with mgcv or R?

The full code is

```
gamm4c <- bam(mood ~ s(time, bs="cr", k=30) +
            s(time, user_id, bs="fs", xt="cr", m=1, k=5)+
            s(time, county_id, bs="fs", xt="cr", m=1, k=5)+
            s(pct_trade_sector, bs="cr")+ 
            ti(time,pct_trade_sector),             
          data=gamm_data, method="fREML")
```

In this model, the DV mood was the weekly measured mood of respondents during some time in the pandemic. Time is the numeric version of the week. Furthermore, we had the county in which the person lives, addressed by the factorial county_id. The research question was whether the county-level variable "percentage of employees in the trade sector" affects the nonlinear time curve of the persons.

Prior to this model I tested baseline models (with only mood and time) and compared a random intercept model, a random slope model, and a random smooth model with the latter being the most predictive. When I run the interaction within a random **slope** model then I get no error...

Any hint is appreciated. In case the paper gets a RR, I bet I will have to run the models again...

All the best,
Holger

Comment: Pretty difficult to diagnose this error without more information. My first guess would be a conflict with another loaded package (e.g. `gam` or `VGAM`). Could be worth only loading the necessary packages for diagnosis. Does it help if you type `gamm4c <- mgcv::bam(...)`?

Comment: Hi, I already tried mgcv::bam(...) but with no success.....It cannot be the variable type either (I guess) as these work with a random slope model (both ID's are factors, the time and moderator are double).

Comment: Assuming that there are no conflicts with other packages, here is what I would do next: i) use `debugonce(bam)` to see where exactly the error occurs and/or ii) remove terms from the model and see whether the error disappears.

Comment: Thanks so far. The error has to do with the line that specifies the random smooth component (s(time, county_id, bs="fs", xt="cr", m=1, k=5)).
I checked with a tutorial provided in 
Sóskuthy, M. (2017). Generalised additive mixed models for dynamic analysis in linguistics: a practical introduction. arXiv preprint arXiv:1703.05339. 

On p. 28 he has the code for the random smooth model that equals mine (I followed his tutorial. For his data and code, the same error emerges. As I said, some month ago everything worked

Comment: You need `xt = list(bs = "cr")`. I don't know when this changed in {mgcv} but it caught me out recently and took some figuring out.